# How to keep GDB tracing in the same emacs frame

Tags: emacs

I use GDB in Emacs 23.2 and while I mostly like it there is one thing that I find very annoying.  When stepping through code if I trace into a function that is located in a source module that is already in an Emacs buffer and happens to be visible in a different frame then that frame is raised and stepping continues there.  Is there a way to have gud just make that buffer visible in the current gdb frame and keep it as the active frame?

Comment: No idea whether or not you still have this problem, but the accepted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3311577/1199226) might be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the exact same problem.  The only way I've dealt with it to date is to close out other frames, so everything appears in the GDB frame, but that's an awful workaround.  I've done some pretty serious searching through the docs and stackoverflow and found these customizations...

1. [pop-up-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151620/how-do-i-make-this-emacs-frame-keep-its-buffer-and-not-get-resized)
2. [sticky windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812192/emacs-preventing-gud-pdb-from-controlling-windows)
3. [dedicated windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43765/pin-emacs-buffers-to-windows-for-cscope/65992#65992)

Hope they help.