# Reuse *compilation* window in another frame

Tags: emacs

How is it possible to enforce `display-buffer-reuse-frames`-like behavior for certain frames with `display-buffer-alist`?

I have tried doing

```
(setq display-buffer-alist
      '(("\\*compilation\\*" .
         (display-buffer-reuse-window '((inhibit-same-window . t))))
        ))
```

, but to no avail.  The documentation is long and cryptic even by Emacs standards, and has no examples.

This is not the same as [question 3311577](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311577/when-using-two-frames-in-emacs-how-do-i-prevent-the-compilation-buffer-from-sho) because `(setq-default display-buffer-reuse-frames t)` is deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to be using the `reusable-frames` entry in your ALIST argument to `display-buffer-reuse-window`, rather than `inhabit-same-window`? (or perhaps you wanted both?)

You also want to be using `add-to-list` rather than clobbering the entire list with `setq`.

**Edit:** My original answer messed up the list structure, as I was using the dotted-pair notation from the documentation, but had omitted one of the dots!

So the correct value is:

```el
(add-to-list
 'display-buffer-alist
 '("\\*compilation\\*" . (display-buffer-reuse-window
                          . ((reusable-frames . t)))))
```

or equivalently:

```
(add-to-list
 'display-buffer-alist
 '("\\*compilation\\*" display-buffer-reuse-window
                         (reusable-frames . t)))
```

I also notice that there's a good `customize` interface for configuring this.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it does not work — it switches my current frame in which I press `F9` to `*compilation*` regardless of whether there is already a frame (X window) with `*compilation*` open, so I end up with two monitors showing GCC output.

Comment: I have also tried setting `inhibit-same-window` to `t`, but it did not help either.

Comment: You've bound `F9` to `compile` ?

Comment: phils, `(global-set-key [f9]   'compile)`

Comment: @phils Should it be F10?

Comment: @Roadowl Probably not?  The key sequences reserved solely for use by end users are "those consisting of ‘C-c’ followed by a letter (either upper or lower case), and function keys <F5> through <F9> without modifiers", so F9 should never be used by anything else, whereas F10 is likely to be (by default it's a global binding to open the menus).  In the end it's your call, though.

Comment: @phils Any thoughts on a Sun Type 5c keyboard US edition hanging through a tmk programmed Teensy off a USB connector to a Linux machine? As you probably know, it has the 10 extra keys on the left (Stop, Again, Props, etc.). (As well as a Help key, a Compose key [with LED!] and an Alt Graph key.)

Comment: No particular thoughts -- but if feel you can make good use of the extra keys in Emacs, go for it.  I don't have a keyboard like that, but most of the 'extra' keys I have are bound to various Emacs things (in some cases this means ensuring that my window manager ignores them).

Comment: Same ;-)  Btw., I forgot: UNIX layout. Have fun!